# Low fps makes chunks load slowly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I make my max fps low, like less than 20, the chunks load super slowly too.

E.g. running around on horse I will just catch up to unloaded chunks.

Why is this? And how can I circumvent this?

I want low fps to prevent my laptop from overheating, but I still want chunks to load properly.

I am on a MacBook Pro with Retina Mid-2015, macOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

Comment: Hm, I'm unsure whether to add the [tag:technical-issues] tag onto this. It's probably a game behaviour and not a technical thing, but I don't know and it sounds very similar to common technical problems.

Comment: Are you in 1.12.2 or in 1.13-pre1? Can you try in the other one and see if it also happens there? And, just in case it's relevant, can you post your hardware specifications, operating system and so on?

Comment: @Fabian I am in 1.8, the same thing happens in every version.

Comment: Is this fixed in 1.15-pre1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Minecraft measures chunk load speed in ticks per frame. The easiest workaround is to install Optifine, and then in `Graphics -> Perfomance` increase `Chunk load speed` and disable `Slow chunks`.

---

**PS**: MacBook Pro is pretty powerful and should not overheat from Minecraft. If it does, ask an expert to remove dust from the cooling system (***do not try to do it yourself***) or close background applications. Your laptop wouldn't benefit much from decreasing FPS.

Comment: I know that the MacBook handles minecraft fine, I just use it alongside several other intensive apps and _that_ causes it to burn into my lap.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug. Report it. Best with a video showing both high and low FPS setting and F3 active.